# Using "IF" in a SELECT statement to check if another column exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I use to `INSERT` all `SELECTED` datas to a new table but i added extra field `IDS_EXIST` and that determine if each data have their ids `NOT NULL` ill `INSERT 'Y'` but if one of them turn `NULL` i will `INSERT 'N'`

Is it possible to use if condition like this in an select statement?

```
SELECT IF(C.ID != NULL AND C.UID != NULL AND C.SID != NULL,'Y','N'),
       C.NAME,
       C.ADDRESS,
       C.DATE 
FROM CLAIMS C
```

cause i know once that IF condition can use like this

```
SELECT IF('condition','value if true','value if false')
```

i reverse my query many times but still get syntax error in query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when comparing with  *not* `NULL`, use `IS NOT NULL`

```
SELECT   IF(C.ID IS NOT NULL AND C.UID IS NOT NULL AND C.SID IS NOT NULL,'Y','N'),
         C.NAME,
         C.ADDRESS,
         C.DATE 
FROM     CLAIMS C
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will work as long as you use `IS NOT NULL` ([working with `NULL` values](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)).

> You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as `=`, `<`, or `<>` to test for `NULL`.

```
SELECT IF(1 != 2 AND 1 != NULL,'Y','N')
```

Returns `N`

```
SELECT IF(1 != 2 AND 1 IS NOT NULL,'Y','N')
```

Returns `Y`

Comment: Well to be fair Kaii does mention a syntax error, so there was some sort of effort applied.

Answer (score 0):

You may try

select case when c.ID is null and c.UID is not null and C.SID is not null then 'Y' else 'N' end